# Unable to retrieve a specific portion of a website through python requests.get()

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, automation, python-requests

I am trying to capture the Ranking Criteria present in the following page using requests.get()

"https://www.topuniversities.com/universities/massachusetts-institute-technology-mit".

The entire HTML code apart from the Ranking Criteria (10 parameters) is fetched. I am unable to figure out why only that 1 section is not fetched.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.topuniversities.com/universities/massachusetts-institute-technology-mit'

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.81 Safari/537.36"}
response = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'lxml')
```

My goal is to capture the exact score along with its respective parameter from the link. For example,

```
parameters_list = ['overall','academic reputation',...]
value_list = ['100','100',...]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you see on the page is loaded from external URL via JavaScript. To simulate this request you can do:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.topuniversities.com/qs-profiles/rank-data/513/410/0?_wrapper_format=drupal_ajax"

payload = {
    "js": "true",
    "_drupal_ajax": "1",
    "ajax_page_state[theme]": "tu_d8",
    "ajax_page_state[theme_token]": "",
    "ajax_page_state[libraries]": "addtoany/addtoany.front,ckeditor_accordion/accordion.frontend,clientside_validation_jquery/cv.jquery.ckeditor,clientside_validation_jquery/cv.jquery.ife,clientside_validation_jquery/cv.jquery.validate,clientside_validation_jquery/cv.pattern.method,core/drupal.form,core/drupal.states,core/normalize,eu_cookie_compliance/eu_cookie_compliance_bare,flag/flag.link_ajax,ga/analytics,layout_discovery/onecol,qs_article/qs_article,qs_firebase_sso/sso-lib,qs_firebase_sso/sso-lib-header,qs_flexreg_user_flow/qs_flexreg_user_flow,qs_global_site_search/search_header,qs_profiles/highcharts,qs_profiles/qs_profiles,qs_profiles/qs_profiles_circle,qs_user_profile/qsUserProfile,system/base,tu_d8/global,tu_d8/node,tu_d8/profile_header,tu_d8/qna_forums,tu_d8/qs_campus_locations,tu_d8/qs_instant,tu_d8/qs_profile_new,tu_d8/qs_profile_new_datalayer,tu_d8/qs_program_tabs,tu_d8/qs_ranking_chart,tu_d8/qs_related_content,tu_d8/qs_similar_programs,views/views.module",
}

headers = {"X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"}

data = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers).json()
soup = BeautifulSoup(data[-1]["data"], "html.parser")

for score in soup.select(".score"):
    name = score.find_next("div", class_="itm-name").get_text(strip=True)
    print(f"{name:<50} {score.get_text(strip=True)}")
```

Prints:

```
Overall                                            100
Academic Reputation                                100
Employer Reputation                                100
Faculty Student Ratio                              100
Citations per Faculty                              100
International Faculty Ratio                        100
International Students Ratio                       88.2
International Research Network                     94.3
Employment Outcomes                                100
Sustainability                                     95.2
```